# How should I index the following MariaDB table?

Tags: database, mariadb

I have this sample table to hold some tenant data and I am not sure how to index it. I've been reading about database compound/composite indexes and came up with the following, based on how I want to query my data:

The test table has 2.396.500 rows and has these columns

- tenant_id   | UNSIGNED BIGINT
- code        | UNSIGNED BIGINT
- status_a    | UNSIGNED TINYINT (0 or 1)
- status_b    | UNSIGNED TINYINT (0 or 1)
- param_a     | VARCHAR(100)
- param_s     | VARCHAR(100)
- param_c     | VARCHAR(100)
- param_b     | VARCHAR(100)
- value_a     | unsigned int
- value_b     | unsigned int

1. I need to query a row by it's code, since it's a tenant table I'll query it as follows
   `select * from myTable where tenant_id = 1 and code = 1`;
2. Besides searching for a specific code, my other filters always includes one of the two status columns "status_a" and "status_b" and "param_a" might also be included. So the query goes as:

```
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_a = 1;
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_b = 1;
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_a = 1 and param_a = 'stuff';
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_b = 1 and param_a = 'stuff';
```

3. Columns "param_s", "param_c" and "param_b" are kind of dependent on each other, due to the app rules. If I'm querying for "param_b", "param_c" will always be present. And if I'm querying for param "param_b", "param_s" will always be present. Query should be as follows:

```
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_a = 1 and param_s = 'stuff_s' and param_c = 'stuff_c' and param_b = 'stuff_b' and param_a = 'stuff_a';

select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_a = 1 and param_s = 'stuff_s' and param_c = 'stuff_c' and param_b = 'stuff_b';

select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_a = 1 and param_s = 'stuff_s' and param_c = 'stuff_c' and param_a = 'stuff_a';
```

4. Columns value_a and value_b are always compared using ">=" or "<=";

Looking for each case individualy, I'd think something as

1. Compound index on tenant_id and code
2. I'm not sure columns "status_a" and "status_b" should be indexed at all (only 0 and 1), but... Indexes on ("tenant_id", "status_a", "param_a") and ("tenant_id", "status_b", "param_a").
3. Index on ("tenant_id", "status_a", "param_s", "param_c", "param_b","param_a") and ("tenant_id", "status_b", "param_s", "param_c", "param_b","param_a")
4. Individual indexes for value columns

But after setting this up I feel like these are too many indexes (is there such a thing)?

Comment: I'm afraid that's too broad and there's not much to say other than: Test it! Do the queries yield "good" plans and are "fast enough"? Fine, you did well. If not, you might need to add other indexes. Is the DDL "fast enough"? Fine, you did well. If not, you might need to remove some indexes (though in my practical experience that almost never happens). Repeat if necessary. If you need help with *one specific* case, reduce the question to that.

Comment: Do some of these query patterns appear far more frequently in production? And, do you always need `SELECT *` or can you use a subset of the columns? Knowing the answer to both of those questions can make a difference to index design. Please [edit] your question to tell us that. It's about [covering indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) and [clustered indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For query #1:

```
select * from myTable where tenant_id = 1 and code = 1;
```

you can create the index:

```
create index ix1 on myTable (tenant_id, code);
```

For the queries in section #2:

```
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_a = 1;
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_b = 1;
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_a = 1 and param_a = 'stuff';
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_b = 1 and param_a = 'stuff';
```

you can create the indexes:

```
create index ix2 on mytable (tenant_id, status_a, param_a);
create index ix3 on mytable (tenant_id, status_b, param_a);
```

For the queries in section #3:

```
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_a = 1 and param_s = 'stuff_s' and param_c = 'stuff_c' and param_b = 'stuff_b' and param_a = 'stuff_a';
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_a = 1 and param_s = 'stuff_s' and param_c = 'stuff_c' and param_b = 'stuff_b';
select * from mytable where tenant_id = 1 and status_a = 1 and param_s = 'stuff_s' and param_c = 'stuff_c' and param_a = 'stuff_a';
```

I would create the somewhat generic index:

```
create index ix4 on myTable (tenant_id, status_a, param_s, param_c);
```

For the inequalities that would depend on the specific query.